# Testing API wrapper with phpspec

Tags: php, tdd, phpspec

I'm trying to create a wrapper for an API class using TDD with phpspec.

I've written a `Client` class which deals with requesting/retrieving data from a REST API which is then mapped to of one several `Entity` classes, so it behaves like an ORM.

I'm a bit stuck now I've come to test and extend the application with TDD. As the `Client` is a dependency of the entity classes (so that they can request their own child objects), I'm struggling with mocking this.

For example, here's what one of the entities, `Comic.php`, might look like:

```
class Comic {

  protected $client;

  public $id;

  public function __construct(Client $client)
  {
    $this->client = $client;
  }

  public function getCharacters()
  {
    // just an example, this would return an array of Character objects
    return $this->client->request("comic/{$this->id}/characters");
  }

}
```

And for the sake of brevity here's what a simplified down version of `Client.php` looks like:

```
class Client {

  public function __construct($publicKey, $privateKey)
  {
    // make token from $publicKey, $privateKey
  }

  public function request($endpoint)
  {
    // use token for cURL request to endpoint and return data
  }

}
```

So how might a test on `ComicSpec.php` for `it_gets_all_characters()` look, as an example?

Hope this makes sense, can provide more info if needed.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure `it_gets_all_characters` would be a thing you test in `ComicSpec` since getting all characters doesn't look like one of `Comic` responsibilities. Right?

What `Comic` must do (its responsibility) is to call the client and trust on it to retrieve the characters. So in `ComicSpec` you should mock `Client` and test that `Comic` calls it with the correct message and parameters:

In `ComicSpec`:

```
function it_gets_all_characters(Client $client)
{
    $this->beConstructedWith($client);

    $client->request(Argument::any())->shouldBeCalled();

    $this->getCharacters();
}
```

Notice you haven't tested the API calling, so you also need a `ClientSpec` to do that. If you use `curl` I think it's basically impossible to test it (without actually calling the service), but maybe you can use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). In `ClientSpec` you would mock the HttpClient and test that `Client` calls it with the correct message and parameters.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Guzzle is basically my client, using an Adapter pattern for this but thanks!